# Stop element from scrolling at the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get this element to scroll which it does but I'd like it to stop scrolling before the footer.

At the moment I have this but the pages don't have the same length so the >= 17900 is not a good solution for me.

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();        
    if (windowTop >= 17900) {
        $(".product-form__item--quantity").addClass("non-fixed");
       $(".product-form__item--submit").addClass("non-fixed");
       $("#ProductPhotoImg").addClass("non-fixed");
       $("#option_total").addClass("non-fixed");
       $(".product-single__title").addClass("non-fixed");
      
       $(".product-form__item--quantity").removeClass("change");
       $(".product-form__item--submit").removeClass("change");
       $("#ProductPhotoImg").removeClass("change");
       $("#option_total").removeClass("change-option");
       $(".product-single__title").removeClass("change");
      
    } else {
        //console.log('a');
        $(".product-form__item--quantity").removeClass("non-fixed");
       $(".product-form__item--submit").removeClass("non-fixed");
       $("#ProductPhotoImg").removeClass("non-fixed");
       $("#option_total").removeClass("non-fixed");
       $(".product-single__title").removeClass("non-fixed");
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you need to fix the snippet

Comment: Oh dude, side stepping your issue for a moment.  You REALLY need to try to not do so many lookups in a scroll handler, which fires a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You have more issues than only finding the footer's position here...

**First** is to find the position of the footer instead of hardcoding a value.
Okay...

**Second** is that you constantly add and remove classes on scroll.
This sure isn't the desired effect.

The `scroll` event fires like a dozen times or more on a single mouse wheel spin.

**Third** is that you force jQuery to lookup for elements, as @Taplar mentionned in comments, each times the script executes (Which is real bad if the script execute constantly!!). This is bad... And unuseful, since this those elements don't change.

So I modified your script... Almost completely :
*;)*

```
// Define an element collection ONCE.
var elementsList = $(".product-form__item--quantity, .product-form__item--submit, #ProductPhotoImg, #option_total, .product-single__title");

// Find the footer's position.
var footerPosition = $("#footer").offset().top;

// Set a flag to prevent the the script action when already done.
var footerVisible = false;


$(window).scroll(function (event) {

    // How many pixels scrolled + viewport height = position of the last pixel at the bottom of the viewport relative to the document's top.
    var viewportBottom = $(this).scrollTop() +  $( window ).height();      

    if (viewportBottom >= footerPosition) {
        if(!footerVisible){
            // Will update classes on the element in the elementslist collection on user scroll enought to show the footer in viewport.
            elementsList.addClass("non-fixed").removeClass("change change-option");

            // Set a flag
            footerVisible = true;
        }
    } else {
        if(footerVisible){

            // Will update classes on the element in the elementslist collection on user scroll from a "visible footer" to a footer below the viewport.
            // In other words, You don't want to do it CONSTANTLY except when the footer is visible and dissapears due to user scroll up.
            elementsList.removeClass("non-fixed");

            // reset the flag.
            footerVisible = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that dude!! Although this makes it much smoother, which is great, it still goes through the footer. I'm using this script in shopify so I'm not sure whether or not it makes a difference...

Comment: In this script, I used `#footer` as a selector for it. It may not be correct. You'll have to find the right selector. Use the code inspector for it. Hit [F12] then (in chrome) [ctrl]+[shift]+[c] to select an element. Mouse over the footer... You will see it's classes or id.